# Как менять значение атрибута value в input через админпанель wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery

Есть калькулятор на jquery. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как 
    менять значение атрибута value в  input через админпанель wordpress? Чтобы в 
    админке были поля, в которых владелец мог бы менять числа-цены, которые 
      менялись бы и в value. 
    Большое спасибо всем, кто ответит!

```
<select name="osnastka" id="osnastka">
    <option value="">Выбор оснастки</option>
    <option value="100">Автоматические оснастки</option>
    <option value="300">Ручные оснастки</option>
    <option value="0">Без оснастки</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

погугли про acf плагин например , или можно все вывести в customizer , acf-ом удобнее , там можно создать группу метаполей и ты можешь вывести в админку текст и вес текста , а select будет выглядить проще типо:

```
<select>
    <?php
    $metas = get_field['calc',$post_id];
    foreach($metas as $meta) {
        echo "<option value= $meta['value'] >$meta['text']</option>"
    }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!